# RelativeLayout "ancorado" no bottom da tela

Tags: java, android, xml

Seguinte quero fazer com que este layout(de id div_externa) abaixo fique ancorado no bottom da tela. 
Mas reparem no seguinte ele esta com 0dp de height propositalmente, nao quero que ela apareça a menos que eu clique no botao.
Ate entao tudo bem funciona perfeitamente...

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF8800"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="osval.com.searchpeople.teste_act"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_teste_act">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/div_externa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FF555555"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"></RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Porem, ao clicar no botao novamente para fechar(que seria no caso voltar a 0dp),
ele pega a ancoragem no topo do layout, sendo assim no primeiro clique do botao ele começa a aparecer de baixo para cima , e nas demais vezes vem de cima para baixo .
o codigo que estou usando para fazer essa mudança de altura do layout é esse :

```js
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.div_externa);
                        LayoutTransition lrl = rl.getLayoutTransition();

                        switch (lock){
                            case "Fechado" :
                                lrl.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
                                rl.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                                lock = "Aberto";
                                break;
                            case "Aberto" :
                                rl.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0));
                                lock = "Fechado";
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

tudo isso esta "dentro" do NavigationDrawer Layout padrao criado pelo android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você só precise setar um `layout_height` diferente de `match_parent` e usar esse atributo:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Prá ocultar/desocultar não precisa mexer na altura, só usar esses comandos:

```
rl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // Oculta
rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Exibe
```

Comment: entao ... eu ja setei o atributo android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
porem ao clicar no botao ele simplesmente ignora e vai pra cima

Comment: Pode ser porque você está mexendo na altura (especialmente porque está setando para match_parent, que ocupa todo os espaço disponível dentro do pai). Tente alterar para o código que sugeri.

Comment: mas a ideia é fazer com que pareça o menu do UBER sabe ? que vai de baixo pra cima e ao fechar ele vai de cima pra baixo

Comment: Também não entendi prá que você está usando um runnable.

Comment: Ja retirei o runnable , é por que estava usando o botao para testar uma resposta do servidor e precisei dele ali hehe,

Comment: e utilisando o setVisibility o layout simplesmente aparece ou simplesmente some ao clicar no botao

Comment: Eu quero mais ou menos o efeito do SnackBar, que vem por padrao ao criar um NavigationDrawer activity, só que sem o timer de fechar sozinho

Comment: O menu do Uber para usar um efeito de transição de elementos compartilhados onde o menu é carregado numa segunda activity quando se clica no botão da primeira activity e os elementos que são "iguais" entre as activities fazem uma animação de transição que dá a impressão de estarem apenas se movimentando na mesma Activity. Não é dificil de implementar: https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html?hl=pt-br#Transitions

Comment: OK Márcio, vou dar uma lida no que mandou ai e daqui a pouco mando uma resposta se consegui ou nao , agradeço pela atençao

Comment: Bom Marcio, foi um pouco mais demorado do que imaginava , mas de fato é bem simples , usei apenas um object animator funcionou perfeitamente , mas com isso que me mostrou acabei fazendo outro efeito que ficou bem mais interessante no app , Valeu mesmo !!!!

Comment: Show de bola!!!